# Uncaught Error: unsupported number: 00940155.184155.1840040

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, amcharts

I'm developing a web application using React. I want to export a chart and data to a single PDF page. Trying to do this, I'm getting the following error

```
pdfmake.js:29058 Uncaught Error: unsupported number: 00940155.184155.1840040
    at t.number (pdfmake.js:29058)
    at r.lineTo (pdfmake.js:37584)
    at d (pdfmake.js:2733)
    at f (pdfmake.js:2601)
    at r.createPdfKitDocument (pdfmake.js:2392)
    at i._createDoc (pdfmake.js:104)
    at i.getBuffer (pdfmake.js:242)
    at i.getDataUrl (pdfmake.js:222)
    at Object.toPDF (export.min.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (TestLineChart.jsx:105)
```

what is reason for that?

Code is below

**TestLineChart.jsx**

```
chart.export.capture({}, function () {
    this.toJPG({}, function (data) {
        let chartHeder = document.getElementById('chartHeder').innerText;

        images.push({
            "text": chartHeder,
            "fontSize": 15
        });

        images.push({
            'image': data,
            "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
        });

        images.push({
            "text": '\n\n',
            "fontSize": 15
        });

        images.push({
            "table": {
                "headerRows": 1,
                "widths": columnStyleArray,
                "body": [ //chart.dataProvider
                        ["DATE VARIANCE", "CURRENT YEAR VARIANCE", "LAST YEAR VARIANCE"],
                        ["5000", "4500", "5100"],
                        ["5000", "4500", "5100"],
                        ["5000", "4500", "5100"],
                        ]
             }
       });

        chart.export.toPDF({
            content: images
        }, function (data) {
            let fileName = chartHeder.split(' /')[0] + '_' + chart.dataProvider[0].date + ' - ' + chart.dataProvider[chart.dataProvider.length - 1].date;
            this.download(data, "application/pdf", fileName + ".pdf");
        });
    });
});
```

there are line 105 is **chart.export.toPDF**, I use [this](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/exporting-pdf-with-multiple-charts-and-related-info/) example to develop this code.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtsampath/bLedgka3/)

Comment: Please provide more information.[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have to share the code/data so it would be possible to understand the source of this issue.

Comment: show us your code ? and from what I get you are trying to assign `00940155.184155.1840040` to a number which is not possible since it has 2 decimals

Comment: I updated qustion. please check

Comment: Please, add an example of `data` value that causes this error.

Comment: try example in error link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your jsfiddle, It's funny but your only problem is, In your table your first `width` value is missing  `%` so change it to `"40%"`

Here I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulex25/5heL1o5m/)

notice I only changed the table's width property
from `"widths": ["40", "30%", "30%"]` to `"widths": ["40%", "30%", "30%"]` adding `%` to the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in case you want to give exact width (like I wanted when I got similar error) is to pass a number, not a string.

I.e: "widths": [40, "30%", "30%"]

Comment: Please give a specific solution like sample code, where to put the width.